# JWT Authentication in a distributed scenario with .NET 5

Tags: .net-core, jwt, .net-5

I'm trying to implement JWT authentication in a .NET 5 WebAPI. Everything works fine until I add more web servers to the application.
How could I store JWT, for example, in a SQL Server database instead of having them in memory on the single server?

Here's the implementation working on a single server:

Startup

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = Context.JwtIssuer,
        ValidAudience = Context.JwtIssuer,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Context.JwtSecretKey))
    };
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet("Login")]
public IActionResult Login(string uid, string password)
{
    var hash = _userManager.GetPasswordHash(uid);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hash))
    {
        return NotFound("Account not found");
    }

    if (!_passwordHasher.Check(hash, password))
    {
        return Unauthorized("Uid/password not correct");
    }

    var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Context.JwtSecretKey));

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: Context.JwtIssuer,
        audience: Context.JwtIssuer,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
        claims: new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, uid)},
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        );

    return Ok(new
    {
        token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
        expiration = token.ValidTo
    });
}
```

Comment: what problem exactly do you have with more web servers and for what purpose do you need to store a JWT in memory or in a database?

Comment: If I log in to the WebAPI and, thus, create a Token on the server side but, on the next call, I fall on another web server, the token won't be valid there. Right?

Comment: the token is validated by it's signature plus the payload (expiration time, role, audience), no need to store it server side. Typically you have one authorization server (issuing the token) and several resource servers. The resource servers have access to the same public key, matching the private key with which the token was signed.

Comment: Oh wonderful, I didn't know! I'll try shortly

Comment: What he means is that `options.SaveToken` shouldn't be true. :) That makes it a proper 'Bearer' token (which means it acts like a key, without the token having to exist on the server side). Of course another requirement is to create the tokens with the same encryption key across different instances, at the very least (but in multi-instance scenarios a centralized authority is better, yes).

Comment: Doesn't the `SaveToken` property simply allow the token to be retrieved from the `AuthenticationProperties`?